DNS resolutions fails in azure linux vm when target key-vault has public access AND private-endpoint
trying to curl or nslookup my azure keyvault from inside a azure vm (behind firewall with application rule for keyvault domain) is not possible because dns-resolutions fails. The keyvault has a private-endpoint configured AND public network access enabled, so dns-resolution or even azcli from my workstation works well but not from inside the VM. Any ideas?

my workstation means? non-Azure VM?, what is your requirement, Do you want to access Azure key vault via Private endpoint without public Access?

If you are trying to check the DNS from outside of the VNet (local workstation), it will provide you with the public IP of the Key Vault, like this, but inside the Azure VM, you will get the Private Endpoint IP.

As written, this isn't a programming question and would probably fit better on [sf] - just read the guidelines first, because as written, this would be off-topic there too, as it's just a "how can I do it" without any effort of your own or specific issue.


DNS resolutions fails in azure linux vm when target key-vault has public access AND private-endpoint

If you check the DNS from outside the VNet (local workstation), it will return the public IP of the Key Vault, but inside the Azure VM, it will return the Private Endpoint IP.

Follow the below steps to resolve the issue
Make sure to enable the Private DNS when creating the Private Endpoint, as shown below.

Key vault Network Configuration

Keyvault Private Endpoint DNS Configuration

If the Private Endpoint is already created, ensure that the Virtual Link and Recordsets in the Private DNS zone are configured correctly.

Once the configurations are done, when I try to check the DNS from outside the VNET, it resolves to the public IP as expected.

When I try to check the same from inside the Azure VM (VNet), it resolves to the Private Endpoint IP, and I am able to access the Key Vault from the VM.


Please see my comment under the question - it's off-topic here (belongs on [sf] - nothing to do with programming, as written) - and shows no details at all from the OP. Not something to write a custom answer for (and your answer doesn't answer any specific problem - it's a custom how-to tutorial). And once again: Please do not upload images of code/data/errors. - images are near-impossible to read for some, and are not copyable as text, editable, etc.

I am just adding the output of the code for clarifications and sharing the full code in code format that I have tried.

So please read the link I shared regarding issues with images. As for full code in code format: code can be properly formatted as text (just use triple-backticks above and below it) - and by doing that, it's fully usable (can be copied, edited, etc). But more importantly: the question shouldn't be answered here. Go back and look at the guidelines - [ask], off-topic questions, and on-topic questions. It's 1) not a programming question; and 2)  just requirements with no [mcve]
